# null reference exception in android view Visibility binding

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have an MvxListView with a few items.
Each item consists of 2 components, one is visible and the other is not (Gone).
The gone component visibility property is bound to a boolean property on the view model,with a 
boolean visibility value converter.

On list item click, i change the boolean property to true, which makes the gone component
to become visible, achieving a sort of expander effect for that particular item.

This works perfectly, 99% of the time.

Once in a while, for some reason i get null reference exception with the following stack trace:

```
691.32 Problem seen during binding execution for from IsInEditMode to Visibility - problem TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.SetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] index, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.SetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object value, System.Object[] index) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource (Boolean isAvailable, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  InnerException was NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I'm not sure if this is MvvmCross issue, or android view issue, but it might be important to note that the gone component has a button. So while all the items in the list are collapsed, there are no buttons, when i expand 1 item, there is a button and the whole list item becomes unclickable, but the button is clickable (this is an unrelated bug which i plan to fix one day, but currently not important for me).

I'm using MvvmCross v3. I admit i'm not using the most latest build (1 month old),
and while its worth a try to see if this happens with new bits, the issue is rare, and 
hard to reproduce.

I have more detailed stack trace information:

```
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___intptr_intptr_intptr_JValue[]   (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) <IL 0x00062, 0xffffffff>
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-bs1/03814ac5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:364
at Android.Views.View.set_Visibility (Android.Views.ViewStates) [0x0003e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-bs1/03814ac5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-8/src/generated/Android.Views.View.cs:4498
at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___int (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00054, 0xffffffff>
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (object,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo) <IL 0x000c6, 0x00553>
at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.SetValue (object,object,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo) <IL 0x0006c, 0x00353>
at System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.SetValue (object,object,object[]) <IL 0x00007, 0x000a3>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.SetValue (object) <IL 0x0007b, 0x0033f>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource (bool,object) <IL 0x00054, 0x001f3>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.<CreateSourceBinding>b__0 (object,Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Source.MvxSourcePropertyBindingEventArgs) <IL 0x0000d, 0x00083>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Source.MvxSourceBinding.FireChanged (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Source.MvxSourcePropertyBindingEventArgs) <IL 0x0000d, 0x000bf>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Source.Leaf.MvxLeafPropertyInfoSourceBinding.OnBoundPropertyChanged () <IL 0x00007, 0x00073>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Source.MvxPropertyInfoSourceBinding.SourcePropertyChanged (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00014, 0x000ab>
at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___object_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0005a, 0xffffffff>
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (object,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo) <IL 0x000c6, 0x00553>
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (object,object[]) <IL 0x00006, 0x0008f>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription`2.OnSourceEvent (object,TEventArgs) <IL 0x0002b, 0x00137>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x00073>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x00073>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x00073>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x00073>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x00073>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x00073>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x00073>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x00073>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x00073>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x00073>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x00073>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x00073>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x00073>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x00073>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x00073>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x00073>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x00073>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00027, 0x00073>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x00059, 0xffffffff>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxNotifyPropertyChanged/<>c__DisplayClass1.<RaisePropertyChanged>b__0 () <IL 0x00021, 0x000f7>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidMainThreadDispatcher/<>c__DisplayClass1.<RequestMainThreadAction>b__0 (object) <IL 0x00006, 0x0005b>
at Android.App.SyncContext.Post (System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback,object) [0x00025] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-bs1/03814ac5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:19
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidMainThreadDispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction (System.Action) <IL 0x0001f, 0x00173>
at Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxMainThreadDispatchingObject.InvokeOnMainThread (System.Action) <IL 0x0000f, 0x00097>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxNotifyPropertyChanged.RaisePropertyChanged (string) <IL 0x0002a, 0x001ff>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxNotifyPropertyChanged.RaisePropertyChanged<bool> (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`1<bool>>) <IL 0x0000a, 0x00087>
at Game.GamePlayerViewModel.set_IsInEditMode (bool) [0x00008] in c:\Users\Roman\Documents\Projects\Games\Game\ViewModels\Players\GamePlayerViewModel.cs:74
at Game.GamePlayersViewModel.HandleSelectPlayer (Game.GamePlayerViewModel) [0x0000f] in c:\Users\Roman\Documents\Projects\Game\Game\ViewModels\Players\GamePlayersViewModel.cs:117
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxCommand`1.Execute (object) <IL 0x00015, 0x000bb>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxListView.ExecuteCommandOnItem (System.Windows.Input.ICommand,int) <IL 0x00021, 0x001b7>
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxListView.<SetupItemClickListeners>b__0 (object,Android.Widget.AdapterView/ItemClickEventArgs) <IL 0x0000d, 0x00087>
at Android.Widget.AdapterView/IOnItemClickListenerImplementor.OnItemClick (Android.Widget.AdapterView,Android.Views.View,int,long) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-    bs1/03814ac5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-8/src/generated/Android.Widget.AdapterView.cs:233
at Android.Widget.AdapterView/IOnItemClickListenerInvoker.n_OnItemClick_Landroid_widget_AdapterView_Landroid_view_View_IJ (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,int,long) [0x00018] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-   bs1/03814ac5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-8/src/generated/Android.Widget.AdapterView.cs:170
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.5e36d7c3-b7bd-4ceb-af22-a12ff6cf17a9 (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,int,long) <IL 0x00029, 0x0009b>
at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.5e36d7c3-b7bd-4ceb-af22-a12ff6cf17a9 (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,int,long) <IL 0x00024, 0xffffffff>
```

Also, the component whose visibility is bound to the property is LinearLayout.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Need moar [logcat](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment%2C_testing%2C_and_metrics/android_debug_log). `NullReferenceException`s can be caused by [dalvik aborting the process](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting#15.unexpected-nullreferenceexceptions); more logcat output would be able to refute this possibility.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace looks does like it is in the call from the viewmodel to the UI.

It suggests that somewhere during the `set` operation on the `Visibility` of the UI component, the code inside that is hitting a `NullReferenceException` - but I can't see any more detail from that stack trace.

The `NullReferenceException` is somewhere inside the set method in the View. It's after the `ValueConverter` has done it's job.

I can't give a solution to this from the information available, and there's nothing I know about in the recent v3 fixes that would have solved this. I'm guessing that this is maybe something to do with rows/views which go out of scope. To work this out, I think maybe you would need to work out how to make this more reproducible (more 99% than 1%).

Some ways to investigate this further:

1. Can you capture any more stack trace information - maybe including logcat trace too?
2. Can you make this happen more frequently?
3. Can you get the same effect to occur in a smaller repro-specific test project?
4. Can you just try 'pot luck' things - e.g. what if you try changing the height of the item rather than the visibility?
5. Can you give any more info here? e.g. what is the `component` who's visibility you are binding? Is it just a standard widget?

Comment: after the update the fact that the null reference is occurring `at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___intptr_intptr_intptr_JValue[]   (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) <IL 0x00062, 0xffffffff>` suggests this is occurring somewhere in the Xamarin->Java binding or **lower** (probably somewhere in the Java). LogCat might help. If not, then sounds like you need to get a more easily repro'd case (at this point I don't think this is an Mvx issue - I *think* this issue would occur if you did the visibility in just a plain `Adapter`)

Comment: yep, unfortunately, i was not able to reproduce this in the last half hour while logcat attached :(

Comment: was able to reporduce it finally. Unfortunately, logcat has no additional information that i didn't post already, same stacktrace.

Comment: This could potentially be an mvvm cross issue. Since the LinearLayout is collapsed at first, maybe there's a race condition when inflating the layout and setting its visibility property. I will see if it happens when the LinearLayout is invisible, instead of Gone.

Comment: From where this is in the stacktrace, I still *guess* it's most likely a situation where the Java and Xamarin objects have somehow lost touch with each other. I guess that if you put the same type of hide/show code outside of mvvmcross binding, then you would hit the same issue... IMO, best bet is to get this reproducible more easily (sorry - I know that's easier to suggest than to do!) and then to lure in someone like @JonPryor - he might have some good suggestions.

Comment: For a nasty (very nasty) workaround you could inherit from `LinearLayout` and implement a `SafeVisibility` property which masks the exceptions  - but I would guess that this might just push the problem somewhere else rather than solving it.

Comment: @Roman: Double-check your logcat, and see if [dalvik is aborting the process](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting#15.unexpected-nullreferenceexceptions). You may need to use the actual `adb logcat` and not the Visual Studio/Xamarin Studio logcat output to see this.

Comment: sorry for the late response, been busy with my newborn son :)
was not able to reproduce this issue since, with adb logcat attached.
will try periodically to reporduce it again, but being this issue is so rare, maybe i'll let it go, or adapt a different UX solution.